# XDLError: ValidationError: "scheme" is not allowed on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to install expo -cli, but it is not work to me. it well show "Error loading DevTools"

```
XDLError: ValidationError: "scheme" is not allowed
at constructUrlAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.16/src/UrlUtils.ts:187:13)
at Object.constructBundleUrlAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.16/src/UrlUtils.ts:19:10)
at getBundleUrlAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.16/src/project/ManifestHandler.ts:104:21)
at getManifestResponseAsync (/@expo/xdl@58.0.16/src/project/ManifestHandler.ts:208:24)
at /@expo/xdl@58.0.16/src/project/ManifestHandler.ts:130:49
```

It is my package.json

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhXMA.png)

Answer (score 8):

I found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2951) with this same problem, so in summary, you need to delete the `.expo` folder, so try running

```
rm -rf .expo
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me. I also delete the .expo folder...